# Question about Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem involving a Markov Time / Stopping Time

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma: Let $W$ be an arbitrary random variable satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|W|] < \infty$, and let $T$ be a Markov time (or stopping time) for which $\mathbb{P}(T < \infty) = 1$. Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[W I_{\{T > n\}}] = 0,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[W I_{\{T \leq n\}}] = \mathbb{E}[W].
$$

This lemma is taken from page 258 of Karlin, Taylor, A first Course in Stochastic Processes (2nd edition). In the proof, I cannot really figure out where exactly the two assumptions are used and in which way. The proof is as follows: First, 
$$
 \mathbb{E}[|W|] \geq \mathbb{E}[|W| I_{\{T \leq n\}}] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb{E}[|W| I_{\{T = k\}}] \to \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[|W| I_{\{T = k\}}] = \mathbb{E}[|W|].
$$ 
Hence
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|W| I_{\{T \leq n\}}] = \mathbb{E}[|W|]
$$
and
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|W| I_{\{T > n\}}] = 0.
$$
Next, observe
$$
 0 \leq | \mathbb{E}[W] - \mathbb{E}[W  I_{\{T \leq n\}}]| = | \mathbb{E}[W  I_{\{T > n\}}] | \leq  \mathbb{E}[|W|  I_{\{T > n\}}] \to 0,
$$
which completes the proof.

In what steps are the two assumptions being used? Or in other words, if the assumptions were not valid, which steps would fail and why? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with dominating function |W|.

Comment: I looked that up, but I am not familiar with measure theory.

Comment: "Not familiar with measure theory" ?? This seems most unfortunate since the question you ask lies entirely in this frame...

Comment: So I have to read up on measure theory then. Can you point out in which step the theorem is used? I assume this theorem only requires the first assumption in the lemma. What about the second one? Thanks.

Comment: The first hypothesis ensures the domination condition, the second one the pointwise convergence, both are necessary for the LDCT to apply.